# How to convert a tautology to Conjunctive Normal Form?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The formula $\varphi \rightarrow ((\psi \rightarrow \sigma) \rightarrow ((\varphi \rightarrow\psi )\rightarrow(\varphi\rightarrow\sigma)))$ is a tautology.

I learned the method to find all rows with formula = 0 to find elements and create a set of conjunction.

So, how to do if I don't have any row where this formula is 0, to find elements to conjunction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every clause is in conjunctive normal form.

($\lnot$ $\phi$ $\lor$ $\phi$)

is a clause, a tautology, and thus in conjunctive normal form.

Comment: But, a CNF is a AND of ORs, correct? So, how ($\lnot \varphi \lor \varphi$) could be a CNF? It looks like a OR of PROPs.

Comment: A CNF is an AND of *1 or more* ORs, yes. So that works. If you must use all three Greek letters, consider $\dots \wedge (\neg \psi \vee \psi) \wedge \dots$.

Comment: @RicardoBrandao See BiranO's comment.